# Serialize XML to class using Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, serialization

How do I DeSerialize my XML (Text) into a Scene (Object) in SL 5.

```
    public static Scene Xml_to_Object(String xml_content)
    {


        Scene scene = null;


        try
        {
            XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Scene));

            scene = new Scene();
            scene = (Scene)reader.Deserialize( xml_content ); //This is wrong!

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            file.Close();
            file.Dispose();
        }


        return scene;

    }
```

And where the xml_content would be

var xml_content = `"<Scene>...xml stuff here .. </Scene>"`;

Scene scene = Scene.Xml_to_Object(xml_content);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
{
   using( var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(xml)) )
   {
       var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (T));
       T theObject = (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
       return theObject;
    }
}
```

The `DataContractSerializer` can be found in `System.Runtime.Serialization`. Use it like this:

```
 Scene scene = Deserialize<Scene>(xml_content);
```

Comment: This looks promising. Almost worked but I get an error `There was an error deserializing the object of type XMLModels.Scene. '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 2, position 1.`

Comment: 0x00 represents null in hexadecimal and null is invalid character in XML

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your class should be have the properties required to be serialized for xml and specify element name on each property of class.
e.g.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Scene")]
[XmlType]
public class Scene
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Type")]
    public string Type{ get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can serialize this as

```
 XmlSerializer xmlReq = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Scene));
 string xml = "<Scene><Name>Mahesh</Name><Type>ABC</Type></Scene>";
 var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(xml));
 var resposnseXml = (Scene)xmlReq.Deserialize(stream);
```

Comment: I dont have the url, I have the XML as a string